# How to Broadcast a Notification to the app when data is updated on Server?

Tags: android, rss, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android app where I need to send a notifications to application from server when data on the server is updated. I have read about GCM and rss feed , but dont know how to implement it.

I want to know which procedure or technique is the best for this and how could I implement it. Please help I am eager to start  working on this?

Comment: GCM will work for you. Try to read more from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html and tutorial from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) you will find steps to follow to create simple GCM client.

Also, a set of samples will be available when you install *Extras/Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library* from the SDK Manager. After installation, the sample sources will be available at %android install path%\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\samples\